# 407 while installing chef-manage

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to install chef-manage using the command

```
chef-server-ctl install chef-manage
```

but I am continuously getting the following error

```
Net::HTTPServerException: 407 "Proxy Authentication Required"
```

I have exported both http and https proxy

```
export http_proxy=http://username_surname:password@your_location_proxy_server:8080 
export https_proxy=https://username_surname:password@your_location_proxy_server:8080
```

But still I am getting 407 error. I have used `%21` instead of `!` in my password. I hope that is not causing the issue.

Comment: That's not a chef issue per se, I bet your proxy is allowing only NTLM authentication (or at least not allowing basic auth)

Comment: This could also be an issue with the add-on installer not having full proxy support, though I'm pretty sure Chef Software got all those issues fixed in the last few Chef Server releases. Either way, you can reach their support team at support@chef.io.